# Using WIFI and LAN at the same time

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, lan

I am hooked up to WIFI and can use the internet, I also am connected to a LAN network that is a different network. The IP for LAN is static as is the Gateway. When my WIFI is enabled I cannot get routed to IP addresses through the LAN gateway. Is there anyway to prioritize which gateway I should be using? Example, WIFI is set to DHCP while giving me an IP of 172.26.167.17 Subnet 255.255.192.0 and Gateway of 172.26.128.1. The LAN port is set to static of 10.145.204.215 Subnet 255.255.255.0 and Gateway of 10.145.204.1. The 10.145.204.xxx network has routing setup to get to 10.145.203.xxx network. I cannot get to devices on the 10.145.203.xxx network without disabling my WIFI connection. Any help is appreciated, thanks much!

Comment: Would be helpful if we knew what OS you were using

Answer (score 0):

You need to use windows metrics to prioritize traffic from one interface to another.  With Windows 7, there was a DOS command to make this happen.  With Windows 10, you can use the GUI to get this done.  Follow this link to see how it's done:
https://pandapow.info/how-to/win10-set-network-adapter-metric/